# Instance variables in class-based generic views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm new to Django and I can't find anywhere which instance variables do class-based generic views have. For example, I know that you can use `self.request` or `self.kwargs`, but is there any list of which other variables can I use? Maybe I can set any variable I need in the `dispatch` function, but what are the defaults?

Comment: One way to pass extra instance variables is to pass extra kwargs into `as_view`, see `__init__` method of the `View` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this is not documented as well as it could be.

The [overview of class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) says this:

> Various useful things are stored on self; as well as the request (self.request) this 
>   includes the positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured 
>   according to the URLconf.

Then, the [reference documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/) lists the attributes created for each specific view. Under `DetailView`, for example, it says:

> While this view is executing, self.object will contain the object that the view is 
>   operating upon.

Another reference you might want to consult is [Classy Class-Based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk/).

Comment: I've never found a better way than just reading the code.  The documentation is silent about enough aspects of class-based views that I don't trust it to be complete.

Comment: @Peter: Reading the code is certainly a good strategy. One nice thing about the ccbv site I mentioned is that each page links directly to the source code of the corresponding view.